# 8051 Dev Board?

Tags: microcontroller, 8051

I picked up a book about the 8051 Microprocessor. It's probably a school book, but I found it for cheap.  It has lab manuals and it's pretty large and looks like it'll be a good learning tool.

Obviously it's an older MP to be learning with, but according to others it's a "classic" and a good learning tool.  But with that being said, how would I go about setting up a "demo" board. Anything special I need to know?  Any suggestions?

Comment: I personally own one of [these 8051-based development boards](http://www.pjrc.com/tech/8051/#boards) which I played around with during some programming classes a few years back. It pretty well has everything you need for true 8051-based stuff.

Comment: The 8051 is a classic, but if it is a good learning tool is a open question. Maybe better to use a modern platform with cheep development kits instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chances are that you outgrow the 8051 after your first project, so I'd rather invest in a more performant development board with a more modern microcontroller. You'll also find a more active community around them, which as far as support goes is worth at least several books.
In the 8-bit arena the [PIC](http://www.microchip.com/) is very popular due to the wide offering by Microchip.
But the most popular these days is [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/en/), based on a performant [AVR](http://www.atmel.com/products/AVR/). There's a handful of Arduino development boards, which can be extended with boards for specific functions. Arduino uses its own programming language.
If you want to be safe for a long time performance-wise, the 32-bit ARM is the way to go. There's a great many manufacturers offering ARM controllers, ranging from very basic to complete SoCs. [NXP](http://ics.nxp.com/lpczone/) is just one of them.
Probably one of the easiest ways to get started with ARM is [mbed](http://mbed.org/).

Comment: Hmmm i've heard alot about ARMS. but I've also heard they are really confusing. And isn't 32 bit ARM overkill anyways? Im steering away from Arduino for now, because I want to Start with ASM first, and into the nitty gritty. (Putting my dev board together myself and such).

Comment: @Sauron in that case hit the microchip free samples site and grab yourself some free PIC chips (16F or 18F series to begin with - they're 8 bit) and enjoy.

Comment: there is no reason why you cannot use asm with the arduino.  Not the best platform for that but very doable.  msp430 is a good platform less than 5 dollars for the launchpad board.  For a little over 10 bucks you can get an stm32 based board from atmel.  The arm may feel like overkill but dont worry about that the instruction set is good, tools are good, and is the leading processor architecture, worth learning.

Comment: for the 8051 silicon labs has the tool stick for 25 dollars.  The 8051 is still kicking and surviving, similar to arm it is not tied to one vendor.  Likely a number of others, dallas semi now maxim may still have some.  plus a number of the easy to use usb devices are/were 8051 based.

Comment: Only problem with ARM is that is it such a good idea to start off with something like that, I can't really find anything for "beginners".

Comment: @Sauron - Did you have a look at mbed? You connect your SBC via USB to your PC, write your C program online (no problems with IDE setup) and upload the compiled code via the USB link. Looks very user friendly to me.

Comment: @stevenvh, thanks Ill take a look. Can you do assembly too (like if you wanted a little to start out?). Also....It looks like theirs a big list of library functions, are you still using ARM's functions or did this guy do his own or what?

Comment: @Sauron - You [can do assembly](http://mbed.org/cookbook/Assembly-Language) with mbed. (Though IMO C is more appropriate for beginners.) I don't have any personal experience with mbed, so I can't give you any details. I only recommended it because it looks interesting enough. There's a forum on the mbed site where you should get answers. You have to register with your mbed's serial number though, so you'll need one of those.

Comment: @Sauron - [This answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5502/how-to-connect-mbed-to-computer/5511#5511) explains how to set up mbed on your PC.

Comment: @Sauron btw, no reason to avoid Arduino hardware. You can flash those cards with normal AVR code if you don't like the Arduino software stack.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to experiment with an 8051 and not a more contemporary architecture, look into some of the USB chips that use an 8051 for their controller core - Cypress amongst others makes them.  This makes it a lot easier to get your software into the device.  Failing that, try to find something with a serial (UART) bootloader programmed into it at the factory.

And be glad you aren't living in the good old days when an an 8751 with EPROM instead of mask ROM cost on the order of $20, and one in a ceramic package with a window so that you could erase that EPROM to have more than one shot at your code was like $70.

Comment: Also worth noting is that the original 8051 was rather slow, it required 12 clock cycles for 1 machine cycle. More modern implementations require 6 or 2 cycles.

Comment: @Federico - add to that that most instructions required (at least) 2 machine cycles, and your 12 MHz 8051 executed only half a million instructions per second.